# Изменение счетчика количества get-запросов

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! Делаю задачу: get-запрос на /urls/:short_url должен возвращать url страницы и увеличивать счетчик запросов на 1 (как я понял, нужно считать именно количество таких get-запросов). Для этого у меня реализована модель Url, которая содержит поля s_url:string и request_number:integer и такой код для метода show в контроллере:

```
def show
    if !Url.where(s_url: request.original_url.to_s).blank?
      url = Url.find_by_s_url(request.original_url.to_s)
      url.request_number += 1
    else
      url = Url.create(s_url: request.original_url, request_number: 1)
      url.save
    end

    render json: url, status: 200

  end
```

И вот какая проблема: значение счетчика повышается только один раз (с 1 на 2), а потом не обновляется вообще. Причем возвращается именно та строка базы данных, которая была изменена изначально. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после прибавления единицы не написал сохранение базы данных:
url.save

После добавления этой строки все работает